# Entity Framework mapping exclude database table columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a table in database named `product` and it has many columns:

- Id
- Name
- Price
- Size
- Color
- ....
- ..

I want to create a class to represent this table only 3 columns. And I will map like this.

```
public class ProductConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public ProductConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("product");

        Property(p => p.ProductId).HasColumnName("id");
        Property(p => p.Name).HasColumnName("name");
        Property(p => p.Price).HasColumnName("price");
    }
}
```

How can I exclude database columns from mapping class?

Comment: Could you add your desired output?!

Comment: Just remove the properties from the class.